# SQL advanced filtering

Tags: mysql, sql, set

I have a table named `route_location` like the following table:

[image]

This table is for a map. There are routes, and each route has a unique `routeID`. The routes contain locations, and the order of the locations appearing in any route is defined by `orderID`. I want to get all locations in all routes, which come after a specific `locationID`(in my current case, `11`), which information is supplied by the `orderID`.

I want to get all locationID from the any route where the orderID exceeds the orderID of a given value.
I want all locations whose orderID is greater than the orderID of locationID=11.

The current answers would be

```
locationID=12,13,16  

[12,13 from routeID=1,

 16 from routeID=2, 

no data from routeID=3]
```

How do I do it? I think it is related with this post:
[Advanced filter in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27253759/advanced-filter-in-sql)

Thank you very much in advance!

**UPDATE:**

> The orderID of the locationID must be greater than the orderID of locationID=11 in the route

Comment: I don't see any `orderID>11`?

Comment: i think you mean to say `locationid >11` right ?

Comment: You need to provide more information about the logic being applied for the expected output. Its not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @DamodarDahal why are you not showing `15` from `2` routeID . what is the filtering criteria ?

Comment: did I provide more info, @AbhikChakraborty ?

Comment: The orderID of the locationID must be greater than the orderID of locationID=11 in the route. That's why I have not included 15 in the answer. Did I answer your question, @AmeyaDeshpande?

Comment: @DamodarDahal now we understand exact requirement ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's still unclear, but you seem to ask for logic applied to an order set: return all data **after** there was a `locationID = 11` on the same route at a previous `orderID`

```
SELECT *
FROM route_location AS rl
WHERE EXISTS
 ( SELECT * 
   FROM route_location AS rl2
   WHERE rl.routeID = rl2.routeID -- on the same route
     AND rl.orderID < rl2.orderID -- any previous order
     AND rl2.locationID = 11      -- had a locationID of 11
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    SELECT *
    FROM route_location AS rl
    inner join route_location AS r2
    on rl.routeID = r2.routeID and  rl.orderID < r2.orderID and r2.locationID = 11
```

Comment: routeID and orderID are COMPLETELY different fields. they can not be compared. See the UPDATE data.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from route_location r1
where orderid > (select orderid from route_location r2
                 where locationId = 11
                   and r1.routeID = r2.routeID)
```